# How to show image in table using PHP

Tags: php, html

I tried the following code to show my SQL database data in a table in my dashboard

```
<tbody>
   <?php
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
     <td><img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width=100px height=100px></td>;
     <td><?php echo $row['class']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['reg_no']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['capacity']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['oname']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['province']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['district']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
     <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle editbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
     <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-circle viewbtn">
       <i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>
     <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle deletebtn">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

But that image column image does not show has an image
Result show like this:

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8zJ.png)

How to solve that problem

Comment: You can have wrong image path in database or you need to specify the image path in src.

Comment: Check file path provided by database

Comment: I feel like the path is correct but the format of the image is not correct. If path were the problem, `alt` tag is missing from the `<img` tag and you would just see a broken image path icon, not the jibberish text that you see right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems your are inserting to the `src` attribute the context of the file rather then the URL of the image.

Answer (score 0):

you are saving the image `content` it self in the DB,
check this out :

https://www.codexworld.com/upload-store-image-file-in-database-using-php-mysql/